# How do I add new line in olx.style.TextOptions text?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have to create label with 2 rows.
in OL 2 I've did it by adding '\n' in the text label but it seems that ol3 doesn't support it:

```
 new ol.style.Style({               
            text : new ol.style.Text(/** @type {olx.style.TextOptions} */ ({
                text:'line 1 \n line 2'
            }))
        })
```

How can I break the line between 1 & 2 ?

Comment: Multi-line labels are not yet supported. But there is a (unmerged) PR for this: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3538

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in the library currently but people have discussed solutions in the ol3-dev Google group as well as pull requests such as: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3538

Comment: Hah, you were faster. :)

Comment: Just to be sure i understand , was this requested , developed and just not commited yet ? Can I get the source and check it myself?

Comment: The source is in the pull request.

Comment: I'm trying to create my own build using that source , next to impossible on windows....