# Multiple lines label OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to create multiple lines for my icon label in OL3. I need to create a four line label. I saw a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383176/how-do-i-add-new-line-in-olx-style-textoptions-text), but there is no answer solving the problem. Does OL3 cover a solution for that now? My '\n' are not working and I couldn't find a way to do it.

```
point= new ol.style.Style({
               image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: 'img/point.ico'

                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: color }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff', width: 2
                    }),
                    text: "Text /n More Text /n Even More /n Last Line"
                })
            });
```

Thanks, any help or links are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there is a pull request about it [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3797). It hasn't seen any action since July, but is still open.

I'd suggest checking it out and doing a custom build with it, or contribute to the PR with testing and suggestions.